# airmong-ng is not found

Tags: linux, fedora, airmon-ng, aircrack-ng

I have installed aircrack using command `sudo yum install aircrack-ng`. But when I run command `airmong-ng` It gives an error: `Bash airmong-ng command not found`. Do I have to install `airmong-ng` individually? I've tried `sudo yum install airmong-ng`, but package not found.

Answer (score 3):

The command should be `airmon-ng`, not `airmong-ng` (there’s no `g` between `n` and `-`), and it needs to run as root:

```
sudo airmon-ng
```

It’s installed in `/usr/sbin` which isn’t on non-root users’ `PATH` by default.

Comment: I have tried it as a root user. But still getting the same error

Comment: @ShahobiddinKhusniddinov A typo in your command `airmon-ng` not `airmong-ng`.

Comment: I have entered command `airmon-ng` but still getting the same error